# Fetch data from mysql by multiple checkboxes with different names

Tags: php, mysql, forms, codeigniter, checkbox

I want to fetch data from a database with multiple check box name arrays but I'm having an issue that it only returns the first selected check box on the name arrays and returns nothing when having different combinations of selections. Please help me.

HERE IS MY VIEW:

```
<div class="col-lg-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Year Level</label>

               <?php if($cat_yr_lvl !== false): ?>
                        <?php foreach($cat_yr_lvl as $data): ?>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="yr_lvl[]" value="<?php echo $data->year_level?>"><?php echo $data->year_level?>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <?php endforeach;?>
                <?php endif; ?>
               </div>
            </div>



                 <div class="col-lg-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Semester</label>
                   <?php if($cat_sem !== false): ?>
                        <?php foreach($cat_sem as $data): ?>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="sem[]" value="<?php echo $data->sem?>"><?php echo $data->sem?>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <?php endforeach;?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <hr>
                    <label>Gender</label>
                    <?php if($cat_gender !== false): ?>
                        <?php foreach($cat_gender as $data): ?>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="gender[]" value="<?php echo $data->gender?>"><?php echo $data->gender?>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <?php endforeach;?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            </div>

                <div class="col-lg-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Midterm Grade Description</label>
                    <?php if($cat_mid !== false): ?>
                        <?php foreach($cat_mid as $data): ?>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="mid[]" value="<?php echo $data->mid?>"><?php echo $data->mid?>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <?php endforeach;?>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <hr>
                    <label>Final Grade Description</label>
                    <?php if($cat_final !== false): ?>
                        <?php foreach($cat_final as $data): ?>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="final[]" value="<?php echo $data->fin?>"><?php echo $data->fin?>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <?php endforeach;?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                 </div>

  </div>
```

HERE IS MY MODEL:

```
    $student_db = $this->load->database('student_db', TRUE);

        $str_dept = implode(",",$this->input->get('dept_id'));
        $str_sy = implode(",",$this->input->get('sy'));
        $str_yr_lvl = implode(",",$this->input->get('yr_lvl'));
        $str_sem = implode(",",$this->input->get('sem'));
        $str_gender = implode(",",$this->input->get('gender'));
        $str_mid = implode(",",$this->input->get('mid'));
        $str_final = implode(",",$this->input->get('final'));

            $student_db->select('*');
            $student_db->where_in('Department_College_dept_id', $str_dept);
            $student_db->where_in('Student_sy', $str_sy);
            $student_db->where_in('Student_year_level', $str_yr_lvl);
            $student_db->where_in('Student_sem', $str_sem);
            $student_db->where_in('gender', $str_gender);
            $student_db->where_in('midterm_description', $str_mid);
            $student_db->where_in('final_description', $str_final);

            $query = $student_db->get('std_v'); 

            return $query->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Second parameter to where_in must be an array.**

Do not use implode before passing parameter to where_in.

for example : replace this

```
$str_dept = implode(",",$this->input->get('dept_id'));
```

by

```
 $str_dept = $this->input->get('dept_id');
```

same for other parameters.

Also ensure whether $this->input->get('dept_id') is an array or not.

It must be an array as it is used as second parameter in where_in.

to check whether $this->input->get('dept_id') is an array or not, use following :

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r($this->input->get('dept_id')); exit;
```

To check last executed query, use following code in your model :

```
echo $this->db->last_query(); exit;
```

Comment: Thank you Abhishek I will try this

Comment: Pleased to help dear...If above answer is helpful than mark it as Useful answer to ensure others as helpful answer.

Comment: I still can't mark it as useful. I'm new here. I don't have a reputation of 15.